# Are there any benefits to using Python for GUI development?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I was looking into Tkinter, but I was wondering if there are any other packages that help with GUI. Even though Java is more robust than python, python is faster to write and would be very helpful if I am just trying to create a quick application. I usually use .Swing and .awt in java to make all of my applications.

Also, Is there something similar to JWS for python? I am looking to add a link on a website that will fire up a python coded application

Thanks

(P.S. I'm using Python 3.2.2)

Comment: The benefit is that Python is pleasant to use. But I'd recommend Qt, not Tkinter. [**Here**](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/) is a good tutorial.

Comment: @blaxpirit: giving a recommendation without explaining why isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love using tkinter with python. It is pretty easy to do, there are lots of examples, and numerous questions with answers on here too! Also, 90% of people with python have tkinter already on their system, making distribution pretty straight forward. I also have had success using [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to create windows executables.

Here is a gui that I wrote in all of ~10 minutes. Once you understand the syntax it is very easy.

[image]

And another more elaborate one that I wrote with [vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/index.html) embedded into the gui for 3D and 2D graphics! The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343759/determining-what-tkinter-window-is-currently-on-top) I asked with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python and tkinter are excellent for developing GUIs. While this is true of most scripting languages, I think these two make a particularly good combination.

For most GUIs, functionality is more important than form (ie: eye candy is not top priority). Even then, it's possible to make very nice looking GUIs with Tkinter. Tk has been my go-to toolkit for close to twenty years. It is most easily used with Tcl since that is its native language, but there's no denying the advantage python has over Tcl as far as built-in functionality goes.

That being said, all of the toolkits available to a python programmer are good. Tkinter's main advantages are that it is extremely easy to use and you probably already have it installed, so the barrier for entry is very low.

Comment: "nice looking" and "eye candy" are straw men. You want a GUI that is "nice-behaving", and "behaves similarly to what the user knows an expects" is a related concept. I'm not saying it's not possible to make *usable* GUIs with Tk, but people who consider the look of a UI as an afterthought probably don't pay much attention to the feel either.

Comment: (Conversely if you're aiming for a poilshed look-and-feel you'll likely need to write enough custom UI code that the choice of toolkit becomes less important.)