# How to put a toplevel window in front of the main window in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, toplevel, topmost

Is there any way to put a toplevel window in front of the main window?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('1280x720')

def create_new_window():
    root2 = Toplevel()
    root2.geometry('500x500')

create_new_window()

mainloop()
```

Here, I want the `root2` window to always stay in front of the `root` window.

I tried using `root2.attributes('-topmost' , 1)`, but the problem is that this line puts the window on top of all the other programs as well.

What I want is that the toplevel window should only be in front of the main window, and it should never go back when I click on the main window.

Is there any way to achieve this in tkinter?

It would be great if anyone could help me out.

Comment: did you tried `root.update_idletasks()` ?

Comment: @Atlas435: This brings the toplevel window in front of the main window, but it does does that only once. So if I click of the main window, the toplevel window goes back again.

Comment: @CoolCloud: I don't see any difference when I use `root2.focus_force()`.

Comment: I read the question wrong, I thought you wanted the window to just be brought to the front, not stay there forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want, i think, is a transient window, you nedd to do:

```
root2.wm_transient(root)
```

From the manual:

wm transient window ?master?
If master is specified, then the window manager is informed that window is a transient window (e.g. pull-down menu) working on behalf of master (where master is the path name for a top-level window). If master is specified as an empty string then window is marked as not being a transient window any more. Otherwise the command returns the path name of window's current master, or an empty string if window isn't currently a transient window. A transient window will mirror state changes in the master and inherit the state of the master when initially mapped. It is an error to attempt to make a window a transient of itself.

Answer (score 3):

So you could do something like this, but it seems buggy for me.
What I have done is to bind the *FocusOut* event to the toplevel that was created, so every time it looses the focus it triggers the event *stackingorder* to put the windos in the right order. You may need to expire this code for several events of your choice, but to get you the idea..
Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def add_toplevel(idx, toplevel):
    if idx == 'end':
        idx = len(toplevels)
    toplevels.insert(idx,toplevel)

def create_new_window():
    root2 = tk.Toplevel()
    root2.geometry('500x500')
    add_toplevel('end',root2)
    root2.bind('<FocusOut>', stackingorder)

def stackingorder(event):
    for toplevel in toplevels:
        toplevel.lift()
        toplevel.update_idletasks()

toplevels = [] #stacking order by index

root = tk.Tk()

create_new_window()


root.mainloop()
```

You are maybe also intrested in this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10391659/13629335

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Atlas345. Your answer helped me a lot, but the method in another answer felt easier for me, so I accepted that one. Please do not take me wrong. Your answer helped a lot. Upvoted!

Comment: @Lenovo360 Agree, by far the better answer.