# Tkinter menu bar goes invisible when checking topmost attribute

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, topmost

I have a larger tkinter app that I wanted to dinamically set the topmost attribute. I am able to achieve what I want, but everytime I check the state of topmost, the selected menu bar on the screen goes invisible.

To reproduce this, consider the MRE below and upon running the code, click the "menu" button on the menu bar, the cascade opens and the exit button shows, watch it vanish after the check_topmost function runs, but the "menu" button is still pressed somehow.

Commenting out either the line that checks the attribute or the line that sets it as True stops the behaviour

```
import tkinter as tk

def check_topmost():
    print(app.attributes('-topmost')) # comment this
    app.after(1000, check_topmost)

app = tk.Tk()
menu_bar = tk.Menu(app)
sub_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
sub_menu.add_command(label = 'exit', command = app.destroy)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label = "menu", menu = sub_menu)
app.config(menu = menu_bar)
app.attributes('-topmost', 1) # comment this
app.after(1000, check_topmost)
app.mainloop()
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong or why is this happening are greatly appreciated!

Please forgive any typos, I wrote this on my phone.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892339/how-to-make-a-tkinter-window-jump-to-the-front) help you?

Comment: @nokla not really, I get the desired output of having the window jump upfront, my problem is that subsequent checks on the topmost attribute cause the menu bar to have some weird behaviour. I say weird behaviour because it only happens when topmost is set to True. Checking it while False doesn't trigger the behaviour.

Comment: I believe it is not recommended to check using the `-topmost` attribute. However there are other ways of checking the window stacking order. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343759/determining-what-tkinter-window-is-currently-on-top

Comment: @oskros thanks for the link, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a fix for your issue, but rather a workaround. It seems like the `topmost` attribute is really weird...  First, it is platform specific. Second, once set, it doesn't just change. If you set `"-topmost", 1` for another window both will have the same attribute. From the [documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/python_stdlib/generated/generated/Tkinter.Tk.attributes.html) I found `"-topmost gets or sets whether this is a topmost window"`. I assume, that once you call the attribute, it not only checks the attribute, but reassigns the value, therefore giving you the weird behavior with the drop-down menu. Interestingly, if you get all attributes at the same time by `app.attributes()`, your drop-down menu is not affected. So you can use this as workaround to check the attribute and only set it if necessary. Most likely, this is not the best solution, but it is the best I could come up with.

```
import tkinter as tk


def set_topmost():
    app2.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    print('window 1', app.attributes())
    print('window 2', app2.attributes())  # as you can see both windows can have the same topmost attribute
    app.attributes('-topmost', 0)  # try the behavior after commenting this out


def check_topmost():
    print(app.attributes())  # this does not affect your window/drop-down menu
    att = str(app.attributes())  # making it a string as workaround

    if "'-topmost', 1" in att:
        print('already set as topmost')
    else:
        print('switch topmost')
        app.attributes('-topmost', 1)  # this will still disrupt your drop down menu

    app.after(5000, check_topmost)  # i set it to 5 seconds to better see the effects


app = tk.Tk()
menu_bar = tk.Menu(app)
sub_menu = tk.Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
sub_menu.add_command(label = 'exit', command = app.destroy)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label = "menu", menu = sub_menu)
app.config(menu = menu_bar)
app.attributes('-topmost', 1) # comment this

app2 = tk.Toplevel()
app2.geometry('500x500')

btn = tk.Button(app, text='set topmost', command=set_topmost)
btn.pack()

app.after(1000, check_topmost)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I had the same suspicion that the check caused a reassignment as well, weird indeed, but oh well... Thanks for providing an alternative method, I'll use that instead!